# How to add array inside the object in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular

Hi I am developing web application in angular 5. I am trying to send data to API. I am supposed to send data in below format to API.

```
 "rules":{  
      "absoluterule":{  
         "create":{  
            "value":[  
               "abb.ability.testmodel1"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
```

Currently I have array createObject which holds values `["IM:abb.ability.configuration", "IM:abb.ability.device"]`. 
From createObject I am passing data to this.create as below.

```
 this.create.push({ value: createObject });
```

I am preparing data as below to send it to api.

```
var data = {

    userRoleId: this.userroleid,
    rules: {
        AbsoluteRule: {
            create: this.create                }
    }
}
```

This is not working as values are not coming in API. Can someone help me to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add a comparison of what you want and what you're getting as of now. Better create a StackBlitz if possible.

Comment: @Nirajan, you have in API: rules.absoluterule.create.value[], (value is the array) and in data: rules.absoluterule.create[{value}] (create is the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
var data = {
  userRoleId: this.userroleid,
  rules: {
    AbsoluteRule: {
      create: this.create
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
var data = {
  userRoleId: this.userroleid,
  rules: {
    absoluterule: {
      create: {
        "value": createObject
      }
    }
  }
}
```